# How to fake SharePoint List (I need IEnumerable<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem>)?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, sharepoint

I'm writing Unit Tests for application, that gets data from SharePoint. Project has interface IListItemCollectionProvider with `IEnumerable<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem> GetListByTitle` method. So, I want fake it and I just need to create my own `IEnumerable<ListItem>`. Unfortunately it's not so easy, because ListItem сan not be created manually.
I tried to use Microsoft.SharePoint.Emulators, but it doesnt help, because 
1)Emulators requires .Net 3.5, instead project's 4.5 to work (this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/545058/Couldplusnotplusloadplusfileplusorplusassemblyplus doesn't work).
2)Emulators supposes using Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList/SPListItemCollection/SPListItem, and I can't find any way to transform it to ListItem.

I  looking for another way get ListItem with my fake data.

Just in case code with Emulators:

```
          using (var emulationScope = new SharePointEmulationScope(EmulationMode.Enabled))
        //throws System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.2.0.0.0.Fakes
        {
            SPSite site = new Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://localhost");
            string listName = String.Format("List{0}", Guid.NewGuid());

            // create a new temporary list   
            Guid listId = site.RootWeb.Lists.Add(listName, listName, SPListTemplateType.GenericList);
            Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList list = site.RootWeb.Lists[listId];
            Assert.IsNotNull(list, "Fail create fake SPList");

            // add fields to list       
            list.Fields.Add("jobname", SPFieldType.Text, true);
            list.Fields.Add("timestamp", SPFieldType.Text, true);
            list.Update();


            // insert 1 item into list       
            Microsoft.SharePoint.SPItem item = list.Items.Add();
            item["timestamp"] = "fake-guid";
            item["jobname"] = "fake-job";
            item.Update();

            Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection listItemCollection = list.Items;
            var clientContext = new ClientContext(site.Url);
            foreach (var elem in listItemCollection)//var is System.Object somehow
            {
                var tmp = elem.ToString();
                tmp = "";
            }

            //need something like  "insert 1 item into list" from above, but ListItem type
            IEnumerable<ListItem> fakeTimeStampsList = null; 

            //using moq here
            var mockDataProvider = new Mock<IListItemCollectionProvider>();
            mockDataProvider.Setup(foo => foo.GetListByTitle(It.IsAny<string>(), null, null))
                .Returns<IEnumerable<ListItem>>(_ => fakeTimeStampsList);

            //how it should work:
            //var result = mockDataProvider.Object.GetListByTitle("NoMetterWhatHere");,
            //where reult is IEnumerable<ListItem> with 1 ListItem inside
            //and it contains {[timestamp, fake-guid]}, {[jobname, fake-job]}

            //Finally instance class (by fake IListItemCollectionProvider), that should be tested 
            var Page = new BaseReportPage(mockDataProvider.Object);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, `SharePoint.Emulators` works with .NET Framework 3.5 only.

If you need to be able to fake SharePoint 2013 objects in a test project which uses .NET Framework 4.5 or later, you may be interested by a third-party NuGet package [SPEmulators](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SPEmulators/). The documentation is available [here](http://writeabout.net/2014/06/21/spemulators-available-on-nuget/). The limitation of this package is that it requires .NET Framework 4.5, and won't work with .NET Framework 4.0.

For those who need a solution for .NET Framework 4.0, a related question on Sharepoint.StackExchange has [an answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/120886/40736) which consists of changing the version of .NET Framework just during the installation of Microsoft's `SharePoint.Emulators` package. As explained [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/545058/Couldplusnotplusloadplusfileplusorplusassemblyplus):

> After installing Sharepoint.Emulator in 3.5 I again change the framework to 4.0 and the project still works.